# Azure (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error). I need a better error message

Tags: azure

I only have one question, how to get a more detailed description of my error?

•  I published my database to Azure.  It works fine.

•  I run my web site from my desk top (Visual Studio 2010) and it accesses my database in Azure with no problems.

•  When I publish my web site to Azure I don't get any errors.  But when I access the web page I get "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error".  I need a more detailed error message.

I have custom Errors mode="Off".  I downloaded from the "FTP Diagnostic Logs" but nothing is there.
I am not using a virtual machine.

Any ideas to get a better error message?

Answer (score 8):

*Taken from the question:*

I figured it out.

1. Go to your website in Azure
2. Go to the configure page
3. Roll down to a heading called site diagnostics
4. Turn on detailed error message then click save at the bottom of the
   page.
5. Your detailed errors will be logged in the diagnostics FTP site.

Don't know why it took me so long to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.user.ini` in the root of your website that contains:

```
display_errors = On
```